# Shiny Reactive Input Value - No Graph Shown, No Error

Tags: r, shiny

A few weeks ago I've asked about reactivity in R - Shiny, and  I still haven't managed to crack the nut. It is driving me insane, I've read 100s of articles about reactivity, but I just can't make it work!

This is what I got so far:

ui.R:

```
column(width = 3,
box(
   title = "Pick a metric",
       status = "primary",
       width = 12,
       height = 200,
       solidHeader = FALSE,
       collapsible = FALSE,
       selectInput("value", "Metric:",
                   c("Pages / Session" = "pageviewsPerSession",
                        "Avg. Session Duration" = "avgSessionDuration"))
                                   )  )
  column(width = 9,
                              box(
                                title = "Title",
                                status = "primary",
                                width = 12,
                                height = 950,
                                solidHeader = FALSE,
                                collapsible = FALSE,
                                          plotlyOutput("Scatter1")
```

server.R:

```
output$Scatter1 <- renderPlotly({ 

datasetInput <- reactive({
  switch(input$value,
     "Pages / Session" =  SourcesDetail$pageviewsPerSession,
     "Avg. Session Duration" = SourcesDetail$avgSessionDuration)
})

p <- plot_ly(SourcesDetail, x = datasetInput(), y = SourcesDetail$visits, text = paste("Source/Medium: ", SourcesDetail$sourceMedium),
         mode = "markers", color = SourcesDetail$medium, opacity = SourcesDetail$sourceMedium, marker = list(size = 15))

})
```

There is no error message, there is simply no graph in my output.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Though I didn't test it out, I think `dataInput` should've been declared outside `renderPlotly`.

Comment: Thanks! It all works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the output to `p` but not outputting `p` itself. Either remove `p <-` or put a single `p` at the end of `renderPlotly`:

Either

```
output$Scatter1 <- renderPlotly({ 

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$value,
           "Pages / Session" =  SourcesDetail$pageviewsPerSession,
           "Avg. Session Duration" = SourcesDetail$avgSessionDuration)
  })

  plot_ly(SourcesDetail, x = datasetInput(), y = SourcesDetail$visits, text = paste("Source/Medium: ", SourcesDetail$sourceMedium),
               mode = "markers", color = SourcesDetail$medium, opacity = SourcesDetail$sourceMedium, marker = list(size = 15))

})
```

or

```
output$Scatter1 <- renderPlotly({ 

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$value,
           "Pages / Session" =  SourcesDetail$pageviewsPerSession,
           "Avg. Session Duration" = SourcesDetail$avgSessionDuration)
  })

  p <- plot_ly(SourcesDetail, x = datasetInput(), y = SourcesDetail$visits, text = paste("Source/Medium: ", SourcesDetail$sourceMedium),
               mode = "markers", color = SourcesDetail$medium, opacity = SourcesDetail$sourceMedium, marker = list(size = 15))
  p
})
```

Comment: I knew it must have been something stupidly tiny... thanks so much Brian, I finally got it!!! :) you made my day